# Display Drop down options for Values saved in Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, module, drop-downs

We created custom module and we saved list of product `Brands` & `Models` in backend. In below image, `Apple, sony, samsung` are brands & `iphone4, iphone4s...etc` are models.

[image]

**Brands**

[image]

**Models**

[image]

We want to create dropdown options for both Brands & Models in frontend. Once we select particular brand from **1st drop-down box**, then only associated models should display in **2nd Drop-down box**.

[image]

**Company/Brand/Block/Frontend/View.php**

```
class Company_Brand_Block_Frontend_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
     protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
        $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head');
        if ($headBlock) {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
                $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
            if ($title) {
                $headBlock->setTitle($title);
            }
            $keyword = $product->getMetaKeyword();
            $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
            if ($keyword) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($keyword);
            } elseif ($currentCategory) {
                $headBlock->setKeywords($product->getName());
            }
            $description = $product->getMetaDescription();
            if ($description) {
                $headBlock->setDescription( ($description) );
            } else {
                $headBlock->setDescription(Mage::helper('core/string')->substr($product->getDescription(), 0, 255));
            }
            if ($this->helper('catalog/product')->canUseCanonicalTag()) {
                $params = array('_ignore_category' => true);
                $headBlock->addLinkRel('canonical', $product->getUrlModel()->getUrl($product, $params));
            }
        }

        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }
    public function getProduct()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(310)
            ->getProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_phone_case', 1);

            $products=$collection->getFirstItem();

            $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($products->getId());
            $p=Mage::registry('product');
        if ($p=='') {Mage::register('product', $product);}
            return  $product;
        }
```

I will give 50 bounty if it works for me.

Comment: where you want to show these both dropdown. You need to use dynamic code for dropdowns

Comment: I need ftp detail for this.

Comment: @Paarth  i posted related code, also please let me know if you want to see some other module related code. also i will post screenshots of db tables also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a select box for `Brands` like :

```
<select id="brand_select">
    <option value="">MY BRAND</option>
    <option value="12">Apple</option>
    <option value="123">Nokia</option>
    <option value="655">HTC</option>
    ......
    <option value="BRAND_ID">BRAND_NAME</option>
    .....
</select>
```

Now create an array for `Models` (with `brand_id`), like :

```
<?php

//Load a model and create an array like this :

/*
$models = array(
            BRAND_ID => array(MODEL_ID => MODEL_NAME,  ..... ),
            BRAND_ID => array(MODEL_ID => MODEL_NAME,  ..... ),
            ...

            );
*/

$models = array(
            12 => array(12 => "iphone4", 45 => "iphone4s", ..... ),
            123 => array(32 => "lorem", 56 => "ipsum", ..... ),
            655 => array(433 => "xyzzz", 546 => "abcd", ..... ),
            ...

            );

//Converting $models array to JSON :

echo "<script>";
echo "var models = ".json_encode($models).";";
echo "</script>";
?>
```

Now add a `jQuery` function :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery( "#brand_select" ).change(function() {
        var brandId = jQuery(this).val();
        jQuery('#model_select').empty().append('<option value="">MY MODEL</option>');

        jQuery.each(models[brandId], function(key,value) {
            jQuery('#model_select').append(jQuery('<option>', { 
                value: key,
                text : value
            }));
        });
    });

    //trigger change event first time if required
    //jQuery( "#brand_select" ).change();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, we already created brands in backend. is we again need to write in code also?

Comment: first make brands select box as I shown, `<option value="BRAND_ID">BRAND_NAME</option>`. Keep Models selectbox empty.

Comment: sorry, i remember what client said, i will try now.

Comment: please check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases)

Comment: I can't find `echo "<script>";
echo "var models = ".json_encode($models).";";
echo "</script>";
`  and jquery script also

Comment: please check [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases) & i added the code like this : http://pasted.co/cceb1162

Comment: keep model selectbox empty, like `<select id="model_select">
<option value="">MY MODEL</option></select>`

Comment: please check now link

Comment: check updated jquery script

Comment: updated script in site, please check link

Comment: complete code of file : http://pasted.co/c9d17d65

Comment: models are not displayig in drop down, is i need to give correct values means `brand_id` and `model_id`   for  codes like this : `12 => array(12 => "iphone4", 45 => "iphone4s" ),` i just copy pasted the code.

Comment: models are not displayig in drop down, is i need to give correct values means `brand_id` and `model_id`   for  codes like this : `12 => array(12 => "iphone4", 45 => "iphone4s" ),` i just copy pasted the code.

Comment: yes, you have to give proper IDs as I show in answer, <option value="BRAND_ID">BRAND_NAME</option> and in Models array also. And I see the link, you provided, that is already changing Models as per Brand changes, isn't  it for you ?

Comment: yes, its chnaging. please give me some time.

Comment: is it working as per what we write in code right, is there any option to get the model and brand names directly from database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42407/discussion-between-anil-suthar-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: This is static work.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1:** Faster way to do this would be to get collection of Models when page is loading and create a json string of Models (with their ids and names) with respective Brands.

When user change selection of brand, then use JavaScript or jQuery to read json string and change options of Models drop-down.

**Solution 2:**
Load only Brands drop-down values on page load and send ajax request to find Models for selected Brand every time. Then populate Models drop-down with resultant values of Models.

Comment: can you please  update the answer with code. if you want to see any other code part of module, please let me know, i will post it like controlers, model, observer files.

Comment: Which solution would you like to implement?

Comment: whichever is easy....

Comment: First solution will have faster response in populating option values. So please populate Brands drop-down on page load and create a json string from Models data and post the code.

Comment: sure than i will go with first one.

Comment: please let me know if you want to check any other part of code.