# Redirect to selected Dropdown options url

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, drop-downs

We are Displaying Drop-down options [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/) using [values Present in Backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125364/display-drop-down-options-for-values-saved-in-backend)

After selecting dropdown options & if we click on "**See Cases**", we are redirecting to particular product [ id : 44 ] using below code.

```
local/Company/Brand/Block/Frontend/View.php

public function getProduct()
    {           
        $product =  Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(44);
            $p=Mage::registry('product');
            if ($p=='') {Mage::register('product', $product);}
            return  $product;
        }
```

But we want to do some ajax coding [ or any other way] & we have to redirect to Particular Brand & Model selected in Dropdown options as [here](http://www.dailyobjects.com/select-mobile-tablet-case-model)

[image]

```
<div class="custom_case">
    <div class="custom_case_left">
        <h1 class="cc1">Custom Cases</h1>
        <h2 class="cc2">Make Your Own design</h2>
    </div>

<?php

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = 'SELECT category_id, category_name FROM ' . $resource->getTableName('outthink_advance_brand_category');

$categories = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$brandsArr = array();

$brandSelect = '<select id="brand_select">';
$brandSelect .= '<option value="">My Brand</option>';
foreach ($categories as $category){
$cat_id = $category["category_id"];

$brandSelect .= "<option value='".$category["category_id"]."'>".$category["category_name"]."</option>";

$query = 'SELECT `outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id, `outthink_advance_brand`.bmodel FROM `outthink_advance_brand` ';
$query .= ' inner join `outthink_advance_brand_category_item` on
(`outthink_advance_brand`.brand_id = `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.brand_id )';
$query .= ' where `outthink_advance_brand_category_item`.category_id = '.$cat_id;

$brands = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

$bArr = array();

foreach ($brands as $brand){
$bArr[$brand["brand_id"]] = $brand["bmodel"];
}
$brandsArr[$cat_id] = $bArr;
}
$brandSelect .= '</select>';

echo $brandSelect;
echo '<select id="model_select"><option value="">My Model</option></select>';
?>


<div class ="cc3">
<div class ="cc4">
<a href="http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases/customcase/"><span class ="cc5"> See Cases > </span> </a>
</div>

</div>



<script>
var models = <?php echo json_encode($brandsArr) ?>;

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery( "#brand_select" ).change(function() {
var brandId = jQuery(this).val();
jQuery('#model_select').empty().append('<option value="">MY MODEL</option>');

jQuery.each(models[brandId], function(key,value) {
jQuery('#model_select').append(jQuery('<option>', {
value: key,
text : value
}));
});
});

//trigger change event first time if required
//jQuery( "#brand_select" ).change();
});
</script>

    <div class="custom_case_right">
    <img height="200px;" width="2000px;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/custom.png'); ?>" >


    </div>
</div>
```

i will give 50 bounty if it works for me.